# What is this teapot and where can I buy it?

Tags: equipment, tea, utensils

I recently watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BTfAzjBTokc#t=48s) and instantly fell in love with the shown teapot. As you can see, the strainer is movable and integrated in the handle very cleverly.

I tried searching for it with the little info that I have, but nothing came out. It looks like Bodum, but it's not. All search variations for ["teapot with integrated strainer"](http://www.google.bg/search?q=teapot+with+integrated+strainer&hl=en&tbm=isch) return very interesting results, but none is the one I search for.

So if someone has any idea what brand it is I will be very grateful.

[image: teapot]

Comment: I accidentally bought a caseful of teapots lke this at a surplus auction about 5 years ago - the top layer was light fittings, I didn't look at the lower layers! They sold quite well on eBay, but I could not source any more. All I can tell is that they came from China.

Comment: Do you have a better picture? I've never seen teapot in this shape.

Comment: Some quick googling found this image on 1 blog, and some discussion of the video.  But no info on the teapot.  Have you tried emailing Michael Wolff?  I get the distinct impression from the video that he owns one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I found the patent for the teapot, but was unable to find anything else about it.  Here is what I have found so far:

http://www.freepatentsonline.com/6655261.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using the assignee name - Emsa Werke Wulf GmbH & Co. KG - I was able to find the teapot. Here is the [URL](http://www.emsa.com/english/ideas-tips/the-emsa-idea/housewares/with-a-tea-lift/)

Comment: Great!  I am glad I could help!  I hope you like your teapot!